# How do I safely detect if Session Scope exists in a service?

Tags: session, grails, scope

I have service that is called both from Quartz (w/o a session scope), and interactively from a Web Flow (w/ a session scope).

When called from the Web Flow, there may be some optional flags set and I would like to safely check for them, IF THEY EXIST.

I'm using session scope because the functions I'm calling are far down a call chain, and passing the options, or scope all the way down will touch a lot of code.

I'm wondering if there is something like:

```
if(someObject.session?.myFlag)
```

where "session" refers to the session scope if called from a web flow, or null if called from Quartz.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the correct approach would be to create a ThreadLocal variable in my Service class. Then the entry point called from the controller, can just set it, if it some corresponding variable is set in the session scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a Filter and ThreadLocal approach.

Create a class with a static ThreadLocal variable which holds a reference to an instance of the class. This instance can then be referenced from anywhere from the executing thread and it will provide access to your variables and flags. This way you are not directly referencing to HTTP session API in your service.

Finally create a Filter in which you set up the ThreadLocal value before executing the rest of the chain. Remember to clear the state of the value after the thread is complete.

```
class MyExecutionContext {
    private static ThreadLocal instance = new ThreadLocal<MyExecutionContext>()
    private HttpSession session
    private ServletRequest request

    // set the state for current thread
    // you can add request here too, if you want/need
    public static void setContext(ServletRequest req, HttpSession s) {
        stateInstance.set(new MyExecutionContext(req, s))
    }

    // get the state of current thread
    public static getContext() {
        return instance.get()
    }

    // clear the current state
    public static void clearContext() {
        stateInstance.remove()
    }

    // private constructor
    private MyExecutionContext(ServletRequest req, HttpSession s) {
        request = req
        session = s
    }

    // now the actual methods to query any kinds of things you need
    // from session (or request if you gave it in the constructor)
    public String getSomething() {
        (String) session?.getAttribute("somethingInSession")
    }

    public String getSomethingElse() {
        (String) request?.getAttribute("somethingInRequest")
    }
}

class ContextFilter extends Filter {
    public void doFilter(...) {
        try {
            MyExecutionContext.setContext(request, request.getSession(false))
            chain.doFilter(req, res)
        } finally {
            // make sure you clear the state
            MyExecutionContext.clearContext()
        }
    }
}

// usage in your service
class YourService {
    def method() {
        if (MyExecutionContext?.context?.something) {
            // value exists in session
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing something similar. I made two entry points to the service - one called from the controller and one called from the service, and then set a ThreadLocal member of the service.

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to already know, accessing the session scope from a service is not something to be encouraged, because the HTTP session should only be used within the web layer (GSPs, controllers, filters, etc.).

Now you didn't hear this from me, but you can access the current session from anywhere like this:

```
def session = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.
        retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session
```

Once you have access to the session you can check if attributes exist or retrieve them using the usual `HttpSession` API.

Comment: And +1 for answering the specific question. Though I didn't test this approach in something that doesn't have Web Request; this is the approach I was looking for. Which was to detect if there was in fact a session somewhere up the call chain.